# The proper way to end a BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, lambda

I recently [read this thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/b18b0a27-e2fd-445a-bcb3-22a315cd6f0d/). So I was thinking of using a lambda expression as a way of calling EndInvoke just as a way to make sure everything is nice and tidy.

Which would be more correct?

Example 1:

```
Action<int> method = DoSomething;

method.BeginInvoke(5, (a)=>{method.EndInvoke(a);}, null);
```

Example 2:

```
Action<int> method = DoSomething;

method.BeginInvoke(5, (a)=>
  {
      Action<int> m = a.AsyncState as Action<int>;
      m.EndInvoke(a);
  }, method);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your 2nd example is slightly more efficient because the "method" delegate instance doesn't have to be captured in the closure.  I doubt you'd ever notice.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if this was possible way back in Jan '09, but certainly now you can just write this:

```
method.BeginInvoke(5, method.EndInvoke, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to read [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/09/asynchronous-fire-and-forget-with-lambdas.aspx) thread on Haacked's blog.
Haven't had a chance to test it, but the gist is in one of the last lines:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback => im.Send(to, from, subject, body));
```

Comment: I actually have read that article, and it seems kind of redundant to use the QueueUserWorkItem if you can pass in a lambda in the call to BeginInvoke.

Comment: QueueUserWorkItem can provide other advanced thread pool management features besides calling EndInvoke. It is preferred to use that.

Comment: It depends on what you are using for. In IIS environment using ThreadPool will use the same threads that are available for request processing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453283/threadpool-in-iis-context