# How can I use parallel processing inside a WCF service code without using the IIS threads?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, parallel-processing, task

Last week in a code review meeting, it was told that using `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.For` in WCF service code is strongly discouraged. It was stated that using parallel programming may increase the time taken to complete one request, but it might lead to thread pool starvation when the server was facing multiple concurrent requests since the worker threads are pulled from the IIS threadpool.

I was running a test in this regard to see myself that this actually happens. I created a WCF REST service (so that I can invoke it using a link) which simply returns a string after completing a time consuming task and hosted this is IIS

```
class UnknownService : IUnknownService
{
    public string GetGreeting()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        //Parallel.ForEach(list, (i) => Thread.Sleep(1000)); <-never use this!
        return "This is complete!!";
    }
}
```

I was trying to simulate a situation in our application (which **mostly** contains synchronous code) where we had a list of items and all of them required some time consuming processing and returns **only** when it is complete.

Testing the code using ApacheBench (following [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287) Steve Sanderson session), I could see that when concurrent requests spikes, the performance was degrading.

So, taking in account the thread pool starvation, I should never use the `Parallel.ForEach` because the extra threads are pulled from the IIS thread pool and the threads are blocked till the processing is complete, making it unavailable to pick another incoming request.

However, reading through [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) Stephen Toub article, where he speaks about async wrappers for sync methods, he mentions that though we might not get the scalability benefits of async code, we can expect the benefits of offloading as it allows long running operations to a different thread. Well, if that was the case, then I can wrap it asynchronously and then do a parallel processing.

```
class UnknownService : IUnknownService
{
    public string GetGreeting()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(list, (i) => Thread.Sleep(1000))).Wait(); 
        //->I must wait for the task since I cannot return until all the list items have been processed.
        //Parallel.ForEach(list, (i) => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        return "Hello there!!!";
    }
}
```

If I take in account only the offloading benefits and not any scalability, i.e, I want to do a parallel processing on the list but not use the IIS threadpool threads (so that they are free to pickup incoming requests), is it a good way to go? How can I ensure that it is not using the IIS threadpool threads for the parallel processing?

**UPDATE**
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4962108/2749476) answer, when a task is created as LongRunning, it uses a dedicated thread instead of using the thread pool thread. Will the context offloading happen even if the action to be performed is synchronous? (I'll have a round of testing with the same and update the results accordingly)

Comment: Read Stephen's article again. Specifically, he talks about offloading in the context of getting the code onto a different *type* of thread. But here, you're moving the task from code running on a thread-pool thread to... code running on a different thread-pool thread. You've not gained anything by doing so. In both cases, the threads belong to the *same* thread-pool.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Is there a way I can parallel process it without making use of the threadpool threads or make it use a different type of thread? Please help.

Comment: To do that you need to update the "other" code to be asynchronous instead of synchronous, if your work is synchronous you can't make it parallel without using thread pool threads.

Comment: Have you considered self-hosting the WCF service instead of using IIS?

Comment: @1.618 - No, I haven't tried that. How will it help me?

Comment: It might help because then you wouldn't be using the IIS threadpool, so you can create as many threads as the OS will let you (I think the main limiting factor is memory -- I'm not a multi-threading expert).

Comment: @1.618 - Thanks for the suggestion. But I will have to stick on to IIS hosting since my application is using the same.