# C# Is action.BeginInvoke(action.EndInvoke,null) a good idea?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

If I want to do a "fire and forget" of some code, but still want to ensure that my memory is cleaned up (per [Why does asynchronous delegate method require calling EndInvoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712741/why-does-asynchronous-delegate-method-require-calling-endinvoke?rq=1)), will the following achieve that goal?

```
Action myAction = () => LongRunTime();
myAction.BeginInvoke(myAction.EndInvoke,null);
```

I've looked around but haven't seen that pattern used anywhere. Rather, people use an annonomoyus method as their callback (such as [The proper way to end a BeginInvoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435772/the-proper-way-to-end-a-begininvoke)) or they define an actual callback method. Since I haven't seen anyone else do this, it makes me think it either doesn't work or is otherwise a bad idea.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any problem with using a method group conversion over a lambda expression.

Comment: If you can add an answer one way or the other if this technique will not cause a memory leak then that would be the answer that I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using a method group conversion instead of a delegate is fine, the `EndInvoke` will still be called in on your `Action`. There is nothing else to be done, since this is a fire and forget call.

Unfortunately, it's somewhat hard to directly irrefutably prove that EndInvoke is called, since `Action` is a delegate and we can't just add a breakpoint on some class in the BCL.

This code will (periodically) inspect some private field of the IAsyncResult that is returned by `BeginInvoke`, which seems to keep track of whether or not `EndInvoke` has been called yet:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 100, 100);
    private static IAsyncResult _asyncResult;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static void LongRunTime()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        Action myAction = () => LongRunTime();
        _asyncResult = myAction.BeginInvoke(myAction.EndInvoke, null);
    }

    static void TimerCallback(object obj)
    {
        if (_asyncResult != null)
        {
            bool called = ((dynamic)_asyncResult).EndInvokeCalled;
            if (called)
            {
                // Will hit this breakpoint after LongRuntime has completed
                Debugger.Break(); 
                _asyncResult = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've double checked using [SOS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benoitsarie/archive/2011/01/17/visual-studio-2010-sos-dll-finding-memory-leaks.aspx) that there aren't any managed memory leaks. I've also tried several other proofs, but they were more circumstantial than this one, I think.

Some interesting I discovered during my investigation: the `myAction.BeginInvoke` call will show up on profilers using instrumentation, but `myAction.EndInvoke` does not.

Comment: There's no point to this that I can see.  Just call LongRunTime() directly inside the task.

Comment: The Task was besides the point, but here's an example without a Task if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Nowdays it could be done like

```
BeginInvoke((Action)(async () =>
{
    // Show child form
    var f = new MyForm();
    f.ShowDialog();
    // Update parent/current
    await UpdateData();
}));
```

Comment: I think you're confusing multi-threaded with asynchronous. The question was about cleaning up resources when using multiple threads. Please look at the answer to the question I linked to in my question for context. `async/await` is about allowing a single thread to continue working while something else is happening in the background.

Comment: Also, it doesn't really make sense to `await UpdateData();` at the end of a lambda that is running in the thread pool. Maybe you are just missing `//do extra work` after the `await`, but as it's written it may confuse people who don't understand _when_ you would want to use `async`/`await`.